# generating the graph using two excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have written code for generating the graph using two sheets data.
The code is

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=SPEC!$B$2:$J$2"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=SPEC!$B$6:$J$6"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=reference_curve!$D$4:$D$303"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=reference_curve!$C$4:$C$303"`
```

It is working correctly  but the problem is I want use range variable for selecting the data for example.

```
dim test as range
test = "=SPEC!$B$6:$J$6"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=SPEC!$B$2:$J$2"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = test
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=reference_curve!$D$4:$D$303"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=reference_curve!$C$4:$C$303"
```

THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

This is how you setup a variable to store a range:

```
dim test as range
Set test = Range("SPEC!$B$6:$J$6")
```